# Using Python API to Update Assets fails with CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER

Tags: visual-flows, python

We have an asset object that has a child asset attached to it.
We have a Process Flow that updates the AccountID and State of the child asset if the parent asset is changed (so the parent and child asset always have the same AcocuntID and State).

I'm truing to use simplesalesforce api to update the parent Asset AccountID and State using

```
sf.Asset.update(AssetId, { 'AccountId': AccountId, 'State': 'Shipped' })
```

This always fails with:

> [{'message': 'The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to
>   trigger a flow.   Contact your administrator for help.', 'errorCode':
>   'CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER', 'fields': []}]

If I disable the process flow it works.

Comment: who ever  has last saved/activated the process flow, will receive an email giving more information about error. the error message you posted in question doesn't tell what's happening

Comment: I get no email at all. I tried explicitly breaking the flow so updating through the web ui causes a failure and then i got the email.
With the current flow, updating over the web UI works fine.

Comment: are you sure the email you got is for the one broke intentionally? because it takes some time to generate an email when a flow is broken, at least in my org.

Comment: Yes, I get no email at all.

Comment: well, without the error its difficult to identify the underlying issue. At least you need to add screenshots of what's happening inside the process flow

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the API version setting in simplesalesforce.
By default it sets the API version to '29.0'.

Once I set the version to '39.0' it worked fine.
So when you create the Salesforce object just pass version = '39.0' to the Salesforce() initializer along with the login tokens.